# Check for multi comment in a text file and print it out

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am trying to loop through a text file, scan it and find multi comments that starts with #| and end with |# and print it out. I am using get function to loop through each characters and the peek function to check for the next character. currently my code is not recognizing the ending comments. Please help.

I have tried looping through each characters comparing it with the multi comments and store it in a vector

```
void Scanner::readingThroughTheFiles(ifstream& inFile)
{
    lineNumber = 0;
    inFile.open(fileName);
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        char c = '\0';
        while (inFile.get(c)) { // loop getting single characters
            tokens = c;
            isAText(inFile);
            isAWord(inFile);
            // isAComment(inFile);
            if (c == '\n') {
                lineNumber++;
            }
            if (c == '#' && inFile.peek() == '|') {
                char next = inFile.peek();
                multipleComment += c;
                multipleComment += next;
                char c = tokens;
                while (inFile.get(c)) {
                    multipleComment += c;
                    if (tokens == '|' && next == '#') {
                        tokenTypes.push_back(multipleComment);
                        values.push_back("COMMENT");
                        // lineNumbers.push_back(lineNumber);
                        multipleComment.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What type does `multipleComment` has?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we can't understand what's going on and will likely not be able to help you.

Comment: String and I am pushing that into a vector of strings

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is here:

```
if (tokens == '|' && next == '#') {
```

This condition can never be true, becasue you're setting `next` only once (a few lines above) and it's value is always `|`. See this line:

```
char next = inFile.peek();
```

And the second problem is that the variable `tokens` has always the value `#`. Maybe you want to do something like?

```
if (c == '|' && inFile.peek() == '#') {
    // rest of your code
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to save the line number you should also check for `\n` in the second while loop. Otherwise your line number won't be increased if you comment spans over multiple lines.

But then you should store the line number temporarly before your enter the second `while` loop. If you don't do that the line number which is stored in your vector `lineNumbers` would be always the last line number.

```
int lineNumberSave = lineNumber;
while (inFile.get(c)) {
    multipleComment += c;
    if (c == '|' && inFile.peek() == '#') {
        // rest of your code
        lineNumbers.push_back(lineNumberSave);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin that was helpful

Comment: No problem. If you like, you could accept this answer as soultion.

Comment: I was able to fix it with your help. My only prob is the line number as you see from my code

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am also trying to store the line number when we hit the end of the line. I though that when you check if the char is a new line , increment it. But it’s like it’s not incrementing and also it doesn’t do anything for blank lines

Comment: @user8628552: Generally this should work. If you post your code (edit your question) it would be easier to help.